# How to set up logging level in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging

Could you tell me how to set up explicitly logging level in Elasticsearch as INFO?
I would like to do that in the file: `elasticsearch.yaml`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [three ways](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/logging.html#configuring-logging-levels) to do it:

A. By updating the cluster settings dynamically (doesn't require any restart):

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "transient": {
    "logger.org.elasticsearch.transport": "TRACE"
  }
}
```

B. By setting the log level directly in `elasticsearch.yml` (requires restart):

```yaml
logger.org.elasticsearch.transport: TRACE
```

C. By setting the log level directly in `log4j2.properties` (requires restart):

```
logger.transport.level = trace
```

Comment: So it will be: '  logger.org.elasticsearch: info  ' , right ?

Comment: Yes, you got it

Answer (score 1):

There are serveral ways, all described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/logging.html).

As you are asking for elasticsearch.yml based config, just pick the according logger based on the [source packages here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch) and add sth. like this for the transport layer:

```yaml
logger.org.elasticsearch.transport: INFO
```

Adding serveral lines will allow you to define different log levels for different functions:

```yaml
logger.org.elasticsearch.transport: INFO
logger.org.elasticsearch.http: DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/logging.html#configuring-logging-levels):
To get more or less verbose logs, use the cluster update settings API to change the related logger’s log level. Each logger accepts Log4j 2’s built-in log levels, from least to most verbose: OFF, FATAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, and TRACE. The default log level is INFO. Messages logged at higher verbosity levels (DEBUG and TRACE) are only intended for expert use.
If you are running elasticsearch inside a pod then shell into the es pod for which you want to change the log level and run the command:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "persistent": {
    "logger.org.elasticsearch.discovery": "DEBUG"
  }
}'
```

You can do that through Postman
Just do a PUT request at the url: http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings  and pass

```json
{
  "persistent": {
    "logger.org.elasticsearch.discovery": "DEBUG"
  }
}
```

in the json under the raw option. You would see response like this:

```json
{
    "acknowledged": true,
    "persistent": {
        "logger": {
            "org": {
                "elasticsearch": {
                    "discovery": "DEBUG"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "transient": {}
}
```

In general, Elasticsearch should be located at localhost:9200 in all ELK Stack configuration files for system-hosted ELK, unless of course you have a different location.
Also you can use the elasticsearch.yml and kibana.yml files to increase the verbosity levels:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: hulk
spec:
  version: 7.8.0
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 3
    config:
      logger.org.elasticsearch: warn
---
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: hulk
spec:
  version: 7.8.0
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: hulk
  config:
    logging.quiet: true
```

If you would like to use environment variables then you could do something like:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: hulk
spec:
  version: 7.8.0
  nodeSets:
  - name: default
    count: 3
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        containers:
          - name: elasticsearch
            env:
              - name: logger.org.elasticsearch
                value: warn
---
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: hulk
spec:
  version: 7.8.0
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: hulk
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kibana
          env:
            - name: LOGGING_QUIET
              value: "true"
```